# how to use postgresql or standard sql to get the total items per transaction and the total items associated with a container

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following structure:

[image]

For each record or transaction, I need to select from items associated with the transaction (QUANTITY) and also I must obtain the total number of items associated with the container of that transaction SUM (QUANTITY) grouped by CONTAINER. The result should be something like this:

[image]

I think this that the following should work but not

```
SELECT TRANSACTION_ID,ITEM, QUANTITY,CONTAINER,SUM(QUANTITY) as SUM  FROM  TX_C_LOAD
GROUP BY TRANSACTION_ID,ITEM, QUANTITY,CONTAINER
```

I think I am stuck with my poor SQL knowledge. Any ideas or SQL functions that I should understand to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a window function:

```
SELECT TRANSACTION_ID,ITEM, QUANTITY, CONTAINER,
       SUM(QUANTITY) OVER (PARTITION BY CONTAINER) as SUM 
FROM TX_C_LOAD
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. I will study about window functions, I really didn't know they existed. I only knew about aggregate functions.